# Have different behavior for specific type in a template function

Tags: c++, templates

I am working on a logHelper function. I have overloaded the << operator and I write the value to a ostream objecct. How do I handle the case for specialized behavior for classes derived from the same base class.

To be more specific, I want to add string returned by what() for an exception.

```
template <class T> 
    LogStream& operator<<(const T& t)
    {
        if (std::is_base_of<std::exception, T>::value)
        {
            std::exception exception = std::dynamic_cast<std::exception>(t);
            m_output << exception.what();
        }
        else
        {
            m_output << t;
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

Comment: You might want to google "polymorphism".

Comment: @H2CO3: Except that _polymorphism_ doesn't really help over here unless you found a way how to correct overload an output operator for `std::exception` obeying the rule to overload operators only if they involve, at least, one user-defined type.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I don't follow. OP wants to do different things based on whether or not an object is derived from a certain base class. Surely you can write an if-else or a switch-case, but then that's C and not C++. This kind of code reuse calls for polymorphysm in an object-oriented language. Syntax is secondary; with appropriate refactoring, this can be easily done.

Comment: @H2CO3: Well, the switching sought is done generically, not using [dynamic] polymorphism: if a certain type property is true, one implementation is used, otherwise a different implementation is used. Since there is no control over the involved types using anything based on object-orientation doesn't quite work. The object-oriented part is the specific type property in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have different code depending on the template argument, you need to somehow provide entirely separate definition chosen at an opportune point in type. For example, you could use

```
template <class T> 
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<std::exception, T>::value, LogStream>::type&
operator<<(const T& t)
{
    m_output << t.what();
    return *this;
}

template <class T> 
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<std::exception, T>::value, LogStream>::type&
operator<<(const T& t)
{
    m_output << t;
    return *this;
}
```

Using `std::enable_if<condition, T>` with negated conditions should enable one or the other implementation.

Comment: awesome Dietmar. It does work. and now I am aware of std::enable_if check.